# copy column from one table and insert in another

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables: `publications` and `books.`

Currently, the table `publications` is empty.

I need to select all the books in the 'books' table with volume "26" and insert it in the publications table. I should also populate the column `publications.component` with 'thesorus'

I tried the sql below but it does not seem correct:

```
INSERT INTO publications (book_fk, component) VALUES (SELECT book_id FROM books WHERE volume = 26, "thesorus");
```

Any suggestion is most appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO publications (book_fk, component) SELECT book_id, 'thesorus' FROM books WHERE volume = 26
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO publications (book_fk, component) SELECT book_id, 'thesorus' FROM books WHERE volume = 26;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert into (field1,field2) select field1, field2 from table1
```